# Is there any way to turn off friend suggestion on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Imagine that I have two friends - Alice and Bob - and I want to prevent Alice from showing up in Bob's friend suggestions ("people you might know"). Can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that directly, but you can ask Alice to block Bob and then Bob will not see her.

To block Bob, Alice can go to Bob's profile and click "Report/Block this Person" and check the "Block this Person" box, or she can go to Account » Privacy Settings » Block Lists » Block Users and enter Bob's name or email address.

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't thought about it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell Alice the following:

> Choose the "Privacy Settings" option
>   in the Account drop-down menu at the
>   top of any Facebook page. Select "View
>   settings" in the "Basic Directory
>   Information" section. Change the
>   setting for "Send me friend requests"
>   to "Friends of Friends"

[Source - How do I prevent myself from appearing in Suggestions?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=12882)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work in this case because Alice is a friend of a friend to Bob.

Comment: Ok my bad I thought the friend of friend worked only if person A intentionally suggested person B (via their profile page) to be a friend to person C. I have no way to test this as I do not have two friends who will want to use their time like this :D